# How to keep variables value alive even after login in Login_Authenticate function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, login-control

I am using below given code to get email, username and password value from the login control in asp.net c# project. But what happens is when authenticate happens all the data vanishes from the variables email, uname and pass. I have need of these three variables in further programming. How can i keep this information persistent, even after login.

```
protected void myLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the email address entered
        TextBox EmailTextBox = myLogin.FindControl("Email") as TextBox;
        string email = EmailTextBox.Text.Trim();
        TextBox UserNameTextBox = myLogin.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox;
        string uname = UserNameTextBox.Text.Trim();
        TextBox PasswordTextBox = myLogin.FindControl("Password") as TextBox;
        string pass = PasswordTextBox.Text.Trim();
        Label1.Text = uname;
        Label2.Text = pass;
        //Label2.Text = myLogin.UserName.ToString();
        
        // Verify that the username/password pair is valid
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(myLogin.UserName, myLogin.Password))
        {
            // Username/password are valid, check email
            MembershipUser usrInfo = Membership.GetUser(myLogin.UserName);
            if (usrInfo != null && string.Compare(usrInfo.Email, email, true) == 0)
            {
                // Email matches, the credentials are valid
                e.Authenticated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Email address is invalid...
                e.Authenticated = false;
                
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Username/password are not valid...
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I use viewstate with login control?

Comment: You persist that information in the database. Yes, that means on any authentication event the database will be hit. Viewstate is per browser page, so no good,  but you can most certainly use session if you looking to not query database every time that information is required.  You don't show the user evaluate method in above code,  but that code hits database every time.

Comment: It gives the error "The name 'emailview' does not exist in the current context", when I use Session[emailview] or Viewstate[emailview].

Comment: I don't see emailview in any of your above code? also, use the LoggedIn event, it triggers after the user is authenticated. it not clear what provider you are using here for authenticaiton, but regardless, I don't see use of session here, and I fail to see how MemberShip.GetUser going to work in a event that triggers before the user is authenticated? As noted, it not clear what you goal here is, but move your code to LoggedIn event, since then memberShip.GetUser will exist.